# Taking Arabic Character Input in C++ from a console application on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, console-application, arabic

Is there any example Code showing How to accept Arabic Input from user in C++ on a console application, in windows?

Comment: The question is quite vague. To take from where? From the console? From a text box?

Comment: What console? What system? Any GUI? This is really too vague.

Comment: Its Windows Console and It will be nice if it will work on Linux too

Comment: and about GUI then i am talking about Win32 GUI

Comment: did you solve this problem? , if you solve it please write the answer

Answer (score 1):

I'll try answer the C++ part. You cannot read arabic characters from console with `cin`. However in `<iostream>` there's a predeclared `wcin` object that is of type `wistream` - a wide-character input stream. And you should read an input not into `string` but into `wstring`.

e.g

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
   std::wstring s;
   std::wcin >> s;
}
```

This was the C++ part, however the question remains whether or not your OS allows wide characters in the console window. HTH

Comment: Amongst the target demographic, I'm confident all OS'es will allow it.